# Inline-block: word was wrapped but extra space in the right side left

Tags: html, css

I need:

[image]

I have:

[image]

So, "exchequer" word was wrapped, however it left pretty wide space in spite of orange div is inline-block. CSS:

```css
.BlockContainer{
  background: blue;  
  width: 400px;
}

.InlineBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    background: teal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #f5511e;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="BlockContainer">
  <div class="InlineBlock">
    Dumpy kibitzer jingles as exchequer overflows.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/fv0jzo9k/

Comment: And what do you want instead? To break the word with a hyphen? To adjust the font size?

Comment: This problem related with padding or width

Comment: Please share complete CSS/HTML.

Comment: [Here is a better fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/fv0jzo9k/1/). Anyway, the explanation is that, by default, inline-blocks do not grow smaller as their contents grow bigger. Not sure what else there is to say. Use `width`.

Comment: Added the complete code.

Comment: this is normal behavior.

Comment: But why? Is inline-block's width must wrap the contains?

Comment: The inner block doesn’t shrink to fit its contents. Use float:left instead of display

Comment: @Christian even float won't solve the issue in this case.

Comment: @TemaniAfif then I’m confused what he’s trying to achieve....

Comment: @Christian I would hardly call the screenshots of "what they need" and "what they get" confusing.

Comment: @MrLister he's simply having a normal behavior but not understanding why. And yes the screenshot cannot give the information needed, also his code too. But try to deacrease the width of outer div an you get it ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks :) I guess it was his confusion that was confusing me :p