# why extra width occurring while resizing inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have placed some items in a row using `display:inline-block` and applied a white background to the parent `div`. In desktop mode the white background is not visible as all items in a row.

But when I resize the window the *...inner elements...* goes to the next line which is fine, but the extra white background is occurring which is the parent background color.

So my question is while I have given ***display:inline-block*** to the parent row, why it is taking 100% width....not the total width of the inner elements.

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/bh2642uz/)**

> *<sub>Note: I have created a fiddle link so that it will be easy to resize the result window. Try to resize the result window you will see the issue. I have also tried the **Flexbox** option but same issue is there too.</sub>*

Comment: i know two duplicates but not easy to find them :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am also searching for a solution for too many hours...but no success...:(

Comment: the issue is that there is no solution as this is a normal behavior and am trying to find the questions where you will understand that this normal and you can do nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041162/inline-block-word-was-wrapped-but-extra-space-in-the-right-side-left

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479571/how-to-center-block-of-inline-blocks

Comment: I found them :)

Comment: Is there any solution using flex

Comment: The problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276

Comment: even with flex there is no real solution but you can always find a workaround, like i did in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479571/how-to-center-block-of-inline-blocks where i modfiy the width of the element a bit so they always fit the size of the container. or consider JS for this